# Scrapy: How to do I prevent a yield request with a conditional item value?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm parsing a list of urls, and I want to avoid saving some url resulted item on the condition of some its value. My code is something like this:

```
start_urls = [www.rootpage.com]
def parse(self,response):
    item = CreatedItem()
    url_list = response.xpath('somepath').extract()
    for url in url_list:
        request =  scrapy.Request(item['url'],callback=self.parse_article)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request

 def parse_article(self,response):
     item = response.meta['item']
     item['parameterA'] = response.xpath('somepath').extract()
     yield item
```

Now I want that in case item['parameterA'] follows a condition, there is no need to "yield request" (so that no saving for this url occurs). I tried add a conditional like:

```
    if item['parameterA'] == 0:
       continue
    else:
       yield item
```

but as expected it does not work, because scrapy continues the loop even before the request is performed.

Comment: Wait, but the only way you get the `parameterA` is by making a request?

Comment: Yes, because I have to "see" what is under that url, the decide if I save it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you should make the decision inside the `parse_article` method:

```
def parse_article(self,response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['parameterA'] = response.xpath('somepath').extract_first()

    if item['parameterA'] != "0":
        yield item
```

Note the use of the `extract_first()` and the quotes around `0`.